# minus between 2 dataframe based on column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe pandas df1, df2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                    'col2': ["D1","D2","D3","D4"],
                    'col3': ["C1","C2","C3","C4"],
                    'col4': ["B1","B2","B3","B4"]})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_ID': ['A', 'D']})


df1=
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
A    | D1   | C1   | B1           
B    | D2   | C2   | B2 
C    | D3   | C3   | B3 
D    | D4   | C4   | B4
```

and df2 :

```
df2=
col_ID |
A      |          
D      |
```

and i want to have , the lines in df1.col1 that are not present in df2.col_ID

```
df1=
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
B    | D2   | C2   | B2 
C    | D3   | C3   | B3
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `isin`

```
df1[~df1.col1.isin(df2.col_ID)]
```

Comment: df1[~df1.col1.isin(df2.col_ID)]

Comment: Thanks both of you.